# What is the alternative to file_unmanaged_save_data()?

Tags: 8

In a custom module, I use this code.

```php
file_unmanaged_save_data($data, 'private://' . $path, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

The documentation for that function has the following warning.

> Deprecated
> In drupal:8.7.0 and is removed from drupal:9.0.0. Use \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface::saveData().

So I tried using `\Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface::saveData($data, 'private://' . $path, FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE)`,
which gives the *Non-static method cannot be called statically*.

Adding `use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface;` at the beginning of the module doesn't change anything.

In the same page, I found also a link to [Unmanaged file functions replaced with a service](https://www.drupal.org/node/3006851) which explains that `file_unmanaged_save_data($data, $destination, $replace)`
has been replaced by `\Drupal::service('file_system')->saveData($data, $destination, $replace)`. It seems to work, but I'm still wandering:

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: try with `self::FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE` or just `FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE`

Comment: I tried without any value for `$replace`parameter (and use the default one) with same result. So I guess the problem is about the beginning `\Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface::saveData`. I tried also with `FileSystemInterface::saveData`. Same error.

Comment: _I'm still wandering: is there another way to do it?_ Why do you need another way to do it?

Comment: Just to understand better: sometimes, I can write `$file1 = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($file1Id)` and it works. And sometimes I write `\Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface::saveData($data, $destination, $replace)`and it fails...

Comment: Except using DI when possible, the code doesn't change much from the last line you show. if the question is whether the function is the correct one to use, that depends from the code you are using. Otherwise, that is the replacement for `file_unmanaged_save_data()`.

Comment: @gbmapo That is because you are calling an interface method. You don't do that, in PHP. You need a class or an object to call its method. Plus, for a class implementing a service, that's not the way to use the class.

Comment: Also `File::load` is for managed files - different API, shouldn’t be compared to the unmanaged file service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Drupal always documents all the methods using `::`, so you need to look closer as to whether the method is static or not.

So if you look at [FileSystem::saveData](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3AsaveData/8.7.x)

> [image]

Its public and not a static. Therefore using `::saveData()` is incorrect, needs to be called with the arrow `->saveData()`

Also, as pointed out, you need to call it with a **class** that implements the `FileSystemInterface`.